# TCP client stops work when try to create a socket connection to arduino server

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp, arduino

I'm trying to make TCP server and TCP client. I have done the server by using Arduino.

```
void setup() {

 pinMode(button, INPUT);   
//Connnect to WiFi Network
Serial.begin(115200);
WiFi.begin(ssid,password);
Serial.println("");
//Wait for connection

while (WiFi.status()!=WL_CONNECTED)
{
  delay(500);
  Serial.print(".");
}
//Print status to Serial Monitor
Serial.print("connected to: "); Serial.println(ssid);
Serial.print("IP Address: "); Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

//Start the TCP server
server.begin();
}

void loop() {

  client = server.available();
  client.setTimeout(10000);
  str=client.readStringUntil('\n');
  if(client){

   if(client.connected()){
    Serial.println("connected to client");

 if(str=="take")
 {
    // read the state of the pushbutton value:
  buttonState = digitalRead(button);

  if (buttonState == HIGH) {

    client.println("open!");
  } else {

    client.println("close");
  }
 }
 else{
   client.println("error");
 }

   client.flush();
   client.stop();

   }
  }
}
```

I think that the server is working because everything works great with netcat.
The client part is an android app, which I've made. The concept is when I press the button in the app, the socket has to connect to the server and change the EditText text. When I press the button every time the program stops. When I debug the program I came to the conclusion that the problem is creating the socket. The server IP is 192.168.1.106 and the port is 3030. Where am i wrong with creating the socket?

```
    View.OnClickListener btns=new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {

                EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
                String str = et.getText().toString();
                String sentence;

           // int mTimeout=10000;

            String modifiedSentence;
                BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            try {
                //clientSocket.setSoTimeout(mTimeout);
                InetAddress ip=InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.106");
               Socket  clientSocket = new Socket(ip,3030);

                DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                sentence = inFromUser.readLine();
                outToServer.writeBytes(sentence + '\n');
                modifiedSentence = inFromServer.readLine();
                et.setText(modifiedSentence);

                clientSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Exception "+e);
            }

        }
};
```